# Upload multiple files in angularjs and backend using laravel (without form tag)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload multiple files without using form tag and using angular js and i am using laravel 5.2.
Below code i tried sending only 1 file it works but on multiple files it fails.

HTML Code

```
<input type="file" class="upload_file pull-right" multiple />
```

JQuery Code

```
$(".upload_file").change(function ()
{
    if (this.files && this.files.length > 0)
    {
         scope.uploadFile(this.files);
    }
});
```

AngularJs Code

```
scope = $scope;

$scope.uploadFile = function(files)
{
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", files);
    $http.post(API_URL + '/offline_upload/file/?token=' + token,fd,
    {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    })
    .success(function(data)
    {
        alert('Done');
    });
 };
```

Laravel PHP Code

```
$files = $request->file('file');
Log::info(count($files));
```

Here the count is always 0

In angularjs instead of files if i send files[0] then only 1 file is sent. But how to send multiple files and retrieve it.

Can someone please help me solve this issue.

Comment: I have few questions. What is the reason not to use form tag? Does it break on client or server side?

Comment: I have multiple images to upload so using form might delay the response from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that with https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload, it supports input type file with multiple parameter and you don't need jquery.

You just instate new uploader object: `$scope.uploader = new FileUploader({var options;});` and put directive into upload form `<input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="uploader"/>` inside your html.

Comment: is it possible within a form

Comment: yes it is, you have to prepare api route and pass also csrf token

Comment: i'll check and get back to you